# jquery mobile string search in page text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

i am building a JQuery mobile App which contains lots of pages with lots of text in it. Initially when a user opens the app, the title of all pages is visible in a list view with search filter at the top. When a user clicks on the title, a new page gets opened with text on it. i want to build a separate page (like search.html) with only a search input box in it. When a person search for a string like "Some string", the tiles of all the pages which contains that term are visible in a list view and after clicking the title, the detailed page gets opened.

Comment: Why don't you simply use the `innerText` or `textContent` (the latter being CSS-agnostic) property of HTML tags?

Comment: thanks for your reply @Powerslave ...actually i am completely new to it...can you give me an example to achieve this..

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in all the text within, say, a `<div id="theTarget">`, then*

```
var theText = document.getElementById("theTarget").textContent;
```

so you can search it like any other string.

Then, based on the return value of `theText.indexOf(searchText)`, you can set your corresponding list view entries' CSS styling based on whether you got `-1` (no match) or not.

*Note: non-jQuery solution